# "Sort Method of Range Class Failed" -error

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that does not cooperate with a macro in our excel processor that we send these excel files through. The only way to get it to work is to copy the values only over to a new spreadsheet and adjust the date format manually. Only once it’s in these new spreadsheets can I send it through the excel processor with no hiccups.

I get "Sort Method of Range Class Failed"  when trying to send the excel files through. I'm not much familiar with VB so I'm hoping someone can take a look at the bare-bone excel sheet data and tell me where the problem exists.

Here's a screenshot of the first few entries of the spreadsheet.

[image]

**Update:**

Upon debugging the error, the compiler stops at the below line:

```
Columns("A:H").Sort key1:=Range("H2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
```

Here's the full code for this section only:

```
'Sort the rows based on the data in column C
Range("H1") = "Index"
Columns("A:H").Sort key1:=Range("H2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Add big formula
Range("I2:I" & DataWBLRow) = BigConcat
Range("J2:J" & DataWBLRow) = FormString3
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the VBA code.

Comment: What @MacroMarc says - We'll need the code to see how and why it fails. You're mentioning the date formats. Most likely in the sheet above it's not actual dates being stored, but rather strings, or the other way around: Your "processor" checks strings for the sorting instead of actual dates.
As long as the `.Sort` method sorts by actual values (and not by displayed text), the dateformat on itself shouldn't matter.

Comment: @RikSportel Please check my updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because in the sheet you're trying to sort the data is in a Table, a so-called `ListObject`. This much is also clear from your sample picture.

That's also why the code does work when you copy-paste the values to another, regular WorkSheet.

In short: Get rid of the Table formatting if altering the VBA is not an option for you. Otherwise, you'll have to test if the Range to sort is part of a `ListObject` or not and if so, then alter the code so that it does a sort on the `ListObject.Range`

Example:

```
Sub SortCols()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set lo = ws.ListObjects(1) 'My Table is range A1:H10

lo.Range.Sort key1:=Range("H2") 'Works perfectly
ws.Columns("A:H").Sort key1:=Range("H2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes 'Error as described in question.

End Sub
```